# future for an event planned?

Tags: future-tense

17. My sister is flying (fly) home from London today. Her flight **will arrive** (arrive) in an hour so I am leaving (leave) for the airport right now to get there in time.

Why Will arrive and not arrive because the arriving of a flight is something  schedulde, so present will be better

http://www.ndj.edu.lb/sites/default/files/images/import/grade-9-all-tenses.pdf

Comment: Because you are not talking about the schedule. Just because it is scheduled to arrive doesn't mean it will arrive.

Answer (score 1):

> Her flight arrive in an hour

sounds just plain wrong. However,

> Her flight arrive**s** in an hour

is an OK alternate (present tense) way of saying

> Her flight will arrive in an hour